# aws ec2 - modify EBS settings in existing AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I change the "DeleteOnTermination" flag in the EBS settings of existing AMI? I think I need to use "`aws ec2 modify-image-attribute`" for that, but not sure of the exact syntax.

EDIT: As a workaround for now, I did the following:

1. Launch an instance from the existing AMI
2. Modify the EBS settings in the launch instance wizard
3. Once instance launched, created an AMI from that instance

That works, but I believe there is much easier way to do it using the modify CLI.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?  I don't understand the EBS part of your question and the delete on termination flag isn't attached to a AMI but rather to the instance that it is used on.

Comment: @stdunbar If you look at an AMI in the AWS console you can see that the EBS volume attributes have a delete-on-terminate flag set at the AMI level.

Comment: Sorry!  I read incorrectly - I was thinking of the terminate flag for an EC2 - please ignore my comment!

Comment: The examples on the `modify-image-attribute` page are definitely lacking. I think if you look at the `describe-image-attribute` docs you will find much more information about how to specify the `--attribute` options. In particular, look at all the attributes it prints. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-image-attribute.html